# How can I delete from a SQL table all the elements that contain a specified word and a date?

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, sql-delete

I've created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (
title TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
date INT DEFAULT '1556399472'
);
```

I would like to delete the columns that contain the word 'apple' and where the post date is 26/04/2019 UTC.
I've tried something like this:

```
DELETE FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%Apple%' AND date >= '1556236800' AND date <= '1556323140';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should work - provided that you have rows that match the conditions.

You can do the date to epoch conversion directly in the database, and I would also recommend using half-open intervals (your code does not take into account the last minute of the day). I would phrase the query as:

```
DELETE FROM news 
WHERE 
    title LIKE '%Apple%' 
    AND date >= strftime('%s', '2019-04-26') 
    AND date <  strftime('%s', '2019-04-26', '+1 day')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `'unixepoch'` modifier can be used in the function [`date()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to return a date in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` from an integer value like `1556236800`:

```
date('1556236800', 'unixepoch')
```

returns:

```
2019-04-26
```

So your query can be written like this:

```
DELETE FROM news 
WHERE title LIKE '%Apple%' 
AND date(date, 'unixepoch') = '2019-04-26'
```